# Insertafter() JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'am trying to insert a JavaScript object with the help of JQuery into a HTML-element like that:

```
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
//added some properties ..

//trying insert after a specific HTML tag
    var selectedListValue=$(selectList) ;
    $( "<tr><td>"+selectedListValue+"</td></tr>" ).insertAfter("#EFAForm_Klein div table tbody tr:last-child()");
```

I'am getting something like this, if I only insert "selectList":

```
"object HTMLSelectElement"
```

or this, if I use "$(selectList)":

```
"[object Object]"
```

Do I need to convert my JS-Object for JQuery ?

Ty for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `selectedListValue` is an jQuery object which when used in string concatenation results in `[object Object]`. In the same way `selectList` is an HTMLElement object whose toString() returns `object HTMLSelectElement`

What you need to do is to append the `tr` then find the `td` inside it and append the `selectList` to it

```
$("<tr><td></td></tr>").insertAfter("#EFAForm_Klein div table tbody tr:last-child").find('td').append(selectList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should omit the `()`:

```
.insertAfter("#EFAForm_Klein div table tbody tr:last");
```

or a better one:

```
$("#EFAForm_Klein tr").filter(':last')
                                      .after('<tr><td></td></tr>').find('td')
                                      .append(selectedListValue);
```